# safari extension: Is there a way to read cookies

Tags: safari

I want to port an extension from Chrome to Safari. Chrome extension is using Chrome.cookies api http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html, is there any similar method for safari extension?

Answer (score 0):

Such API is available for plugins only. The only workaround is to inject script then send  document.cookie back to background page

Comment: Not possible for httponly cookies